# Cannot resolve symbol 'AppCompatActivity' -- NO SOLUTION

Tags: java, android

I am currently developing an android application.
Everything has been working fine, up until the point I decided to add my project to firebase.
I did the steps `Tools > Firebase > Authentication`.
I created the project and added firebase to my application.

5 seconds later, I get the `Cannot resolve symbol 'AppCompatActivity' error`.

I know there are lots of other threads on this issue, and I have read them.

However, no solution seems to work for me. I have tried:

```
>- Syncing project with gradle files.
>- Change the implementation version in app.gradle
>- Invalidate caches and Restart
>- Delete .idea folder in project path
>- Uninstall and then reinstall Android Studio
```

All of these with no success.
Is there anything else I can do about this? Why does this error occur anyway? Did I mess something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this issue by uninstalling and reinstalling Android Studio (again) but this time to another location than the initial one.

Initially it was installed under `D:\someFolder\Android Studio\`
Installing it to the default path `C:\Program Files\Android Studio\` seemed to be the only solution for me

Answer (score 0):

I'm willing to bet you don't have the appcompat depency implemented in your gradle

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```

Comment: I did have the dependency implemented. As stated in my post, everything worked well until I connected my app to firebase (this means that I had the dependency implemented). I guess connecting to firebase triggered some sort of a bug in the IDE. From what I understand, the cause is unknown for the moment.
However, I managed to fix this issue by uninstalling and reinstalling Android Studio (again) but this time to another location.

Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

I had a related issue. cannot resolve AppCompatActivity suddenly happening despite it previously working and everything looking fine: import, gradle dependency etc. Invalidate cache and restart not working.

Fix: Check for a new Android Studio and Gradle update. In this case updating from Android Studio 4.0 to 4.1